# Iterating without incurring the cost of IF statements

Tags: c++

My question is based on curiosity and not whether there is another approach to the problem or not. It is a strange/interesting question, so please read it with an open mind.

Let's assume there is a game loop that is being called every frame. The game loop in turn calls several functions through a myriad of `if` statements. For example, if the user has GUI to false then don't refresh the GUI otherwise call `RefreshGui()`. There are many other `if` statements in the loop and they call their respective functions if they are true. Some are `if/if-else.../else` which are more costly in the worst case. Even the functions that are called, if the `if` statement is true, have logic. If user wants raypicking on all objects call `FunctionA()`, if user wants raypicking on lights, call FunctionB(), ... , else call all functions. Hopefully you get the idea.

My point is, that is a lot of redundant if statements. So I decided to use function pointers instead. Now my assumption is that a function pointer is always going to be faster than an `if` statement. It is a replacement for if/else. So if the user wants to switch between two different camera modes, he/she presses the `C` key to toggle between them. The callback function for the keyboard changes the function pointer to the correct `UpdateCamera` function (in this case, the function pointer can point to either `UpdateCameraFps()` or `UpdateCameraArcBall()` )... you get the gist of it.

Now to the question itself. What if I have several update functions all with the same signature (let's say void `(*Update)(float time)` ), so that a function pointer can potentially point to any one of them. Then, I have a vector which is used to store the pointers. Then in my main update loop, I go through the vector and call each update function. I can remove/add and even change the order of the updates, without changing the underlying code. In the best case, I might only be calling one update function or in the worst case all of them, all with a very clean while loop and no nasty (potentially nested) if statements. I have implemented this part and it works great. I am aware, that, with each iteration of the while loop responsible for iterating through the vector, I am checking whether the `itrBegin == itrEnd`. More specifically `while (itrBegin != itrEnd)`. Is there any way to avoid the call to the if statements? Can I use branch prediction to my advantage (or am I taking advantage of it already without knowing)?

Again, please take the question as-is, i.e. I am not looking for a different approach (although you are more than welcome to give one).

> EDIT: A few replies state that this is an unneeded premature optimization and I should not be focusing on it and that the if-statement(s) cost is minuscule compared to the work done in all the separate update functions. Very true, and I completely agree, but that was not the point of the question and I apologize if I did not make the question clearer. I did learn quite a few new things with all the replies though!

Comment: If each of these functions is doing a "large" task (like refreshing the GUI), surely the cost of doing a single comparison is utterly inconsequential in comparison?  Have you actually profiled to see what percentage of the time you spend in your driver loop?  I would wager that this "optimisation" is not worth the cost in code obfuscation.

Comment: *[...] so please read it with an open mind"* This kind of statement makes me *so* much more likely to read what follows with attention to how it might be legitimately closed. But...um...if you're using a polymorphic language--like for instance C++--why don't you leverage that feature of the language to solve this problem? It's a classic use case for showing how OOP code can be cleaner than not object imperative code. ::sheesh::

Comment: +1 Interesting question with good intentions.

Comment: It sounds to me like you are prematurely optimizing your code at the expense of maintainability. Have you profiled your code to show this idea improves performance?

Comment: @Oli: I agree. Like I said in the question, it is more of a curiosity based question. Also, the way I have done it currently has the benefit of re-ordering the calls, which is very very useful.
@Sam: Yes it is. Again, this is a question based more on curiosity. It is like asking the question `which is better, ++itr or itr++`

Comment: @Samaursa: I don't necessarily disagree with the idea of having a vector of function pointers to allow dynamic control of what things you want to do (although there may be better options).  But I do disagree with the idea of worrying about the end-of-loop comparison!  It's completely irrelevant unless we're talking about the inner loop of the 80% section of your code.  At the top-level of your application, you want to "optimise" for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> there is a game loop that is being called every frame

That's a backwards way of describing it.  A game loop doesn't run during a frame, a frame is handled in the body of the game loop.

> my assumption is that a function pointer is always going to be faster than an if statement

Have you tested that?  It's not likely to be true, especially if you're changing the pointer frequently (which really messes with the CPU's branch prediction).

> Can I use branch prediction to my advantage (or am I taking advantage of it already without knowing)?

This is just wishful thinking.  By having one indirect call inside your loop calling a bunch of different functions you are definitely working against the CPU branch prediction logic.

> More specifically while (itrBegin != itrEnd). Is there any way to avoid the call to the if statements?

One thing you could do in order to avoid conditionals as you iterate the chain of functions is to use a linked list.  Then each function can call the next one unconditionally, and you simply install your termination logic as the last function in the chain (longjmp or something).  Or you could hopefully just never terminate, include `glSwapBuffers` (or the equivalent for your graphics API) in the list and just link it back to the beginning.

Comment: And not just branch prediction! Using function pointers will prevent the compiler from inlining, which could drastically reduce the optimization opportunities - the overhead of a function call (which inlining avoids) is several times that of a simple if statement. If the code is inlined and in the instruction cache, it could be _several hundred times_ faster than the function pointer call!

Comment: My last comment wasn't meant to discourage you from using a container of function pointers, by the way - it could be a fine way to keep track of dynamically changing requirements. Just that you should not fret over an occasional if statement. Furthermore, you might wish to consider using C++ classes with virtual functions (as this is tagged c++), or functors instead of the more c-ish function pointers. That's a matter of taste though

Comment: @Ben: That is exactly what I looking for! Thank you
@Matthew: :) Like I said in the question (and my comments to Sam) the technique solves another problem which is changing the order of updates at runtime. I totally agree that I should not be fretting over these micro optimizations but this is a question based more on curiosity, like `which is better ++itr or itr++`

Comment: Best case scenario for this is if your compiler does tail call optimization, then you can use a continuation-passing style.  Each function receives not only the time (frame number?) but also a pointer to the next pair (function, list next pointer).  At the end of the function, it reads both elements of the pair simultaneously and calls the function passing in the list next pointer.

Answer (score 5):

First, profile your code. Then optimize the parts that need it.

"if" statements are the least of your concerns. Typically, with optimization, you focus on loops, I/O operations, API calls (e.g. SQL), containers/algorithms that are inefficient and used frequently.

Using function pointers to try to optimize is typically the worst thing you can do. You kill any chance at code readability and work against the CPU and compiler. I recommend using polymorphism or just use the "if" statements.

Comment: Polymorphism is just an addition layer of indirection (probably with horrid locality) on top of a function pointer.

Comment: Compilers know how to deal with polymorphism, but function pointers are pure chaos from an optimization standpoint. Polymorphism says "you'll get an object kind of like this" while function pointers say "I'm going to shuffle the deck and deal you a card and you'll like it"

Comment: Huh? Function pointers carry just as much type information as virtual function tables. A compiler is perfectly within its rights to assume that *if there no public APIs accept a argument of a particular function pointer type*, then *every function pointer of that type in the compilation unit is one of the known functions of that type*. That's just as strong as any assumption the compiler can make about polymorphic classes.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this is asking for an event-driven approach.  Rather than checking every time if you need to do something, monitor for the incoming request to do something.

I don't know if you consider it a deviation from your approach, but it would reduce the number of if...then statements to 1.

```
while( active )
{
    // check message queue
    if( messages )
    {
        // act on each message and update flags accordingly
    }

    // draw based on flags (whether or not they changed is irrelevant)
}
```

EDIT: Also I agree with the poster who stated that the loop should not be based on frames; the frames should be based on the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If the conditions checked by your ifs are not changing during the loop, you could check them all once, and set a function pointer to the function you'd like to call in that case. Then in the loop call the function the function pointer points to.